# reportlab Form reuse with changing data

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am trying to use a reportlab Form to generate multiple pages with the same draw actions.  This would be used to draw an image and a table, but the documentation does not expain how to use it any any detail.

the documenation says:

```
def forms(canvas):
    canvas.beginForm('a_form')
    spumoni(canvas)
    canvas.endForm()
    # then do it
    canvas.doForm('a_form')
```

What I don't understand is how this works, lets say my draw function is

```
def draw_table(canvas, data, image):
    table = get_table(data)
    table.drawOn(0,0, canvas)
    image.drawOn(100,100, canvas)
    return canvas
```

how do i call `canvas.doForm('a_form')` for each set of data on multiple pages in one document?

Comment: You need to call `canvas.showPage()` to finish the current page. All additional drawing will be done on another page. The documentation goes on to say "Warning! All state changes (font changes, color settings, geometry transforms, etcetera) are FORGOTTEN
when you advance to a new page in pdfgen. Any state settings you wish to preserve must be set up again
before the program proceeds with drawing!"

Comment: so do I have to redefine the form for each page?

Comment: I don't know. Probably, but you can always just try it and see.